# php search function failing with single quote entry

Tags: php, mysql, search

Ok, I have been on this for 1 hour now.. I am missing something very simple ? I need a new set of eyes on this ? I searched here and found a few things and tried to implement , but still came up short .

I have magic quotes turned off:

My search is for **Sam's Club**

In the database it is entered as : **Sam's Club** as well

Simple search function:

```
$q = htmlspecialchars($q);
// changes characters used in html to their equivalents, for example: < to &gt;
$q = mysql_real_escape_string($q);
// makes sure nobody uses SQL injection

$raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM this, this2 WHERE this.TypeID = this2.TypeID AND this.status = 'Active' AND this.endDate >= CURDATE()
AND (`Title` LIKE '%".$q."%')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Still coming up empty result?

Obviously if I search for **Sam** it will query a result?

Here are two images from my phpMyAdmin:

[image]

[image]

**SOLVED**

I found the problem. I was including another list of functions in my header that I forgot about. That was messing with the variable.

Thanks for the troubleshooting! I still learned a ton!!

Comment: You should switch to PDO or Mysqli, mysql is deprecated.

Comment: So, what are you getting when you search `Sam's Club` ?

Comment: No error, just blank result ?

Comment: What happens when you `echo $q` just before the query?

Comment: You need `htmlspecialchars` when *outputting* to a web page, not when you search in a database. And you need to escape `%` and `_` with `addcslashes` when doing a LIKE search.

Comment: I am getting Sam&#039;s Club when I echo this ?

Comment: Try running that query straight from phpmyadmin or whatever mysql client you are using to see the error that is thrown.

Comment: Skip the first row totally...

Comment: Exactly, that's why you should get rid of `htmlspecialchars`, like Ryan said.

Comment: You're searching for Sam&#039;s and not for Sam's which was the intention. (because you're using htmlspecialchars)

Comment: Strange ? When I search in phpMyAdmin I get the results, and the query gets converted to this:
WHERE `Title` LIKE 'Sams''s'

Comment: The query I just ran from SQL ( in the results window )

Comment: Have you tried without the first row in the code?

Comment: Move the `this.TypeID = this2.TypeID` from your `WHERE` clause, and turn it into a `JOIN` (just a friendly suggestion): `[LEFT] JOIN this on this2 ON this.TypeID = this2.TypeID`. Also `SELECT *`?, just don't do that please

Comment: Yes, but still no results, however it is echo Sam's Club now

Comment: @MarcelKorpel Never use `addslashes`. Please do not tell people to do this.

Comment: @tadman: I wrote `addcslashes` to escape `%` and `_`.

Comment: How does the actual row you're searching in (in the db) look like?

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld Sam's Club

Comment: You uploaded two images with `Sams's Club`, which is different from `Sam's Club`.

Comment: yeah, i realized that, i was just adding it to show you what phpMyAdmin does ? It does come up with the result ( when I spell it right )

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest getting rid of `htmlspecialchars()` it is converting your quote to `&apos;` or even `&#039;`.

So when it tries to search the database it is using `Sam&apos;s Club` or `Sam&#039;s Club` as your search, but it won't be there because it is saved as: `Sam's Club`.

```
$q = mysql_real_escape_string($q);
// makes sure nobody uses SQL injection

$raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM this, this2 WHERE this.TypeID = this2.TypeID AND this.status = 'Active' AND this.endDate >= CURDATE()
AND (`Title` LIKE '%".$q."%')") or die(mysql_error());
```

**Please run this and reply with the string that is generated.**

```
$q = mysql_real_escape_string($q);
echo "SELECT * FROM this, this2 WHERE this.TypeID = this2.TypeID AND this.status = 'Active' AND this.endDate >= CURDATE() AND (`Title` LIKE '%".$q."%')";
```

Comment: Ok , got rid of htmlspecialchars(), but still no dice ? Do I need to write a small function to replace characters before running the query ?

Comment: Can you `echo` the query string just before you execute it and paste it here so it's more clear what you're actually executing?

Comment: It is echo Sam's Club before and after now, but still no dice. I do have a $q = (isset($_GET['q']) ? $_GET['q'] : ""); before all this code too ?

Comment: please echo out your full query. `echo "SELECT * FROM this, this2 WHERE this.TypeID = this2.TypeID AND this.status = 'Active' AND this.endDate >= CURDATE() AND (\`Title\` LIKE '%".$q."%')"`

Comment: I did echo $raw_results and came up with this:
Resource id #13

Comment: I added two images from my database

Comment: you're searching for `Sam"s Club` and not `Sam's Club` (note that one is a quote and one is an apostrophe).

Comment: Or those could be two apostrophes.

Comment: That is the strange thing in phpMyAdmin , I search for it with a single quote and then it returns the results page and it turns the ' into '' ? ( see above in purple and green image )

Comment: When I meant echo out the query, I didn't mean the result of mysql_query. Please look at my update.

Comment: SQL STRING=*SELECT * FROM this, this2 WHERE this.TypeID = this2.TypeID AND this.status = 'Active' AND this.endDate >= CURDATE() AND Title LIKE '%Sam's%'*

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
   echo 'value q before=*' . $q . '*';

   $q = mysql_real_escape_string($q);
   echo 'value q after=*' . $q . '*';
   $q2 = mysql_escape_string($q);
   echo 'value q2 after=*' . $q2 . '*';

    // makes sure nobody uses SQL injection

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM this, this2 WHERE this.TypeID = this2.TypeID AND this.status = 'Active' AND this.endDate >= CURDATE() AND `Title` LIKE '%".$q."%'";
    echo 'SQL STRING=*'.$sql.'*';
    $raw_results = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    echo 'RAW RESULTS=' . print_r($raw_results, true);
```

Comment: With an equal sign you can't use wildcards like `%`.

Comment: @MarcelKorpel - I know that but it seems like OP's question is about having it equal. The db-row is Sam's Club and the search is Sam's Club. I don't think LIKE %Sam's Club%' would give any result if a row in the db is Sam's Club. Or am I wrong?

Comment: `%` matches 0 or more characters.

Comment: Added 2 images from my phpMyAdmin above

Comment: @eberswine - What's result of sql string? (edited my answer above)

Comment: @MarcelKorpel - Ok thanks about the information about the percentage sign in sql! :-)

Comment: SQL STRING=*Resource id #13*      Query was empty

Comment: @eberswine: No, not the resource, the query string. What is `$sql` after you insert `$q`?

Comment: @eberswine Do you really have a table called 'this' ?

Comment: ok here it is: SQL STRING=*SELECT * FROM this, this2 WHERE this.TypeID = this2.TypeID AND this.status = 'Active' AND this.endDate >= CURDATE() AND `Title` LIKE '%Sam's%'*

Comment: No table called this, just replacing the real table name!

Comment: If that's what you're getting you have not correctly escaped that variable and your statement has an injection bug that's causing it to fail.

Comment: @eberswine Strange, `$q` should be `Sam\'s` after using `mysql_real_escape_string`. Another reason to switch to prepared statements. And why do you replace the table name? That's a source of bugs...

Comment: @eberswine - OK about this. If you copy that SELECT * FROM this, this2 WHERE this.TypeID = this2.TypeID AND this.status = 'Active' AND this.endDate >= CURDATE() AND Title LIKE '%Sam's%' TO the phpMyAdmin you get different results?

Comment: no, just on here, not in the script

Comment: I get this in phpMyAdmin if I run the SQL #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's%'' at line 1

Comment: Both `'%Sam\'s%'` and `'%Sam''s%'` are valid from an escaping perspective. You need to have one of these or it won't work. You are missing the `mysql_real_escape_string` call.

Comment: None of this would be an issue if you were using PDO and [SQL placeholders](http://bobby-tables.com/php) because this is done for you automatically if you use them correctly. In this case, "You have an error in your SQL syntax" should be translated to "you have a giant SQL injection hole in your application."

Comment: @eberswine - What's the value q before? (see my editied answer)

Comment: value q before=*Sam's*

Comment: Strange. I've edited my answer again. What results do you get of value q after and value q2 after ?